# What happens when you add a varying term to the thresholds in ordered logistic regression?

Tags: stata, discrete-data

Specifically, I would like to know what ologit in STATA estimates because I tried a simulation  and I had really weird outputs. So I'd like to know how exactly adding a varying term to each threshold e.g. 2*x affects the outcome of the ordered logistic model.

Comment: Please qualify "weird outputs" and in general add more information about what you did and what you expected to happen.

Comment: Yes I wasn't very clear..Actually I am also not really sure what to expect. When I simulate my data such that the thresholds are constant I clearly get the appropriate cutoff points. But when I add to each threshold  a variable so that my threshold becomes :
previous constant threshold + 2*x, I am actually not sure what stata computes at ouput, which is definitely not equal to the constant threshold.

Comment: There exist ordered logit models that allow you to specify heterogeneity in the cutpoints by allowing them to depend on regressors ($\kappa_{ji} = \exp(\boldsymbol{Z}_i'\boldsymbol{\gamma}_j)$); for example, in [this paper by Gary King](http://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/3965182/King_EnhancingtheValidity.pdf?sequence=2). But you should think carefully about your data to decide that this is indeed what is going on. There are many ways of modelling heterogeneity in ordered logit models, and you should pick one based on subject matter knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is actually much simpler. If for instance I model the threshold to be: $  \beta_0+x_i \beta_1 +u_i \leq a_i + x_i \gamma$ then will the coefficient that Stata gives me for x will actually be $\beta_1 - \gamma$ ? Because that's  what I suspect from my simulations

Comment: Is that how you are simulating your model? Then yes, that is what Stata's estimates of the coefficients on the regressor $X_i$ will be. Note that $\beta_1$ and $\gamma$ are _not_ separately identified in your model -- in effect, you might as well be simulating from the model $\beta_0 +X_i(\beta_1 -\gamma)+ U_i \leq \kappa_1$ for the first category $\kappa_1 < \beta_0 +X_i(\beta_1 -\gamma)+ U_i  \leq \kappa_2$ for the second category and so on.